# wxpython : How to AppendText one by one (as any key pressed)

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython

In this code, I have a wx TextCtrl to show information (info_window), and a function print_info() to receive texts from my main script, append them to TextCtrl. The texts are appended at the same time, but I need them to be appended like this:

hello 1

-press any key

hello 2

-press any key

hello 3

Is there any way to append the strings one by one after pressing any key by keyboard?

I suppose the key should be the function press_any_key(). It may associated with any type of wx event, but I don't know how to write the function properly.

```
import wx
class Frame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__ (self, parent, id = wx.ID_ANY, title = wx.EmptyString, pos = wx.DefaultPosition, size = wx.Size(500,300), style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE|wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL)

        self.SetSizeHints(wx.DefaultSize, wx.DefaultSize)

        bSizer1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        self.info_window = wx.TextCtrl(self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.EmptyString, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.Size(450,250), wx.TE_MULTILINE|wx.TE_READONLY|wx.TE_RICH2)
        bSizer1.Add(self.info_window, 0, wx.ALL, 5)

        self.SetSizer(bSizer1)
        self.Layout()

    def print_info(self, string):
        self.string = string + '\n'
        self.info_window.AppendText(self.string)
        self.press_any_key()

    def press_any_key(self):
        pass


def main():
    frame.print_info('hello 1')
    frame.print_info('hello 2')
    frame.print_info('hello 3')


app = wx.App()
frame = Frame(None)
frame.Show()
main()
app.MainLoop()
```

Thanks Rolf of Saxony. I solved my problem, the key point is wx.Yield(). I modified the code as below

```
import wx
import time

class Frame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__ (self, parent, id = wx.ID_ANY, title = wx.EmptyString, pos = wx.DefaultPosition, size = wx.Size(500,300), style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE|wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL)

        self.SetSizeHints(wx.DefaultSize, wx.DefaultSize)

        bSizer1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        self.info_window = wx.TextCtrl(self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.EmptyString, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.Size(450,250), wx.TE_MULTILINE|wx.TE_READONLY|wx.TE_RICH2)
        bSizer1.Add(self.info_window, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        self.info_window.Bind(wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN, self.go)

        self.SetSizer(bSizer1)
        self.Layout()
        self.go_status = False

    def print_info(self, string):
        self.waitkey()
        self.string = string + '\n'
        self.info_window.AppendText(self.string)
        self.go_status = False

    def go(self, event):
        self.go_status = True


    def waitkey(self):
        while self.go_status == False:
            wx.Yield()
            time.sleep(0.1)


def main():
    frame.print_info('hello 1')
    frame.print_info('hello 2')
    frame.print_info('hello 3')


app = wx.App()
frame = Frame(None)
frame.Show()
main()
app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not pretty but I couldn't think of a easier way to do it.

```
import wx
import time
class Frame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__ (self, parent, id = wx.ID_ANY, title = wx.EmptyString, pos = wx.DefaultPosition, size = wx.Size(500,360), style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE|wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL)
        self.SetSizeHints(500,360)
        bSizer1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.info_window = wx.TextCtrl(self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.EmptyString, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.Size(450,250), wx.TE_MULTILINE|wx.TE_READONLY|wx.TE_RICH2)
        self.message = wx.StaticText(self,-1,("Press any key"))
        self.keyinput = wx.TextCtrl(self,-1)
        bSizer1.Add(self.info_window, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        bSizer1.Add(self.message, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        bSizer1.Add(self.keyinput, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        self.SetSizer(bSizer1)
        self.Layout()
        self.Show()
        self.keyinput.SetFocus()

    def print_info(self, string):
        self.WaitOnKey()
        self.string = string + '\n'
        self.info_window.AppendText(self.string)


    def WaitOnKey(self):
        while self.keyinput.GetValue() == "":
            wx.Yield()
            time.sleep(0.2)
        self.keyinput.SetValue("")

def main():
    frame.print_info('hello 1')
    frame.print_info('hello 2')
    frame.print_info('hello 3')


app = wx.App()
frame = Frame(None)
main()
app.MainLoop()
```

The code is self explanatory with the exception of `wx.Yield()`. This returns control back to the `MainLoop` which means that the program doesn't freeze. Essentially while the program waits for key input, control is passed back to the main loop every 2/10ths of a second, to see if anything else is going on. This allows the program to continue to perform normally.

Note: This will not work with function keys. For that I think you would have to find a way to `bind` to a key event and use `event.GetKeyCode()`

Comment: Thank you! The function wx.Yield() is a GREAT hint! I have modified my code, Binding wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN and a go() function to the info_window. Now the code runs in my way exactly.

Comment: Glad to be of help